# Scrapy Crawler Stops In The Middle Of Crawl

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I've run into an issue with a Scrapy spider. I scraping a list of urls from a txt file and, in the middle of the scrape, the scrapy spider keeps closing. 
Here is my general scraper logic

```
class DomainArticlesSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "domain_articles"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    f = open("/domain_urls.txt")
    start_urls = f
    def parse:
    item = DomainItem()
    ...
    return item
```

The spider will end with:

```
2014-10-08 21:18:31-0400 [domain_articles] ERROR: Error downloading <GET url>: TCP connection timed out: 110: Connection timed out.

2014-10-08 21:18:31-0400 [domain_articles] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-10-08 21:18:31-0400 [domain_articles] INFO: Stored csv feed (6848 items) in: culture_metadata2.csv
2014-10-08 21:18:31-0400 [domain_articles] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/exception_count': 36,
     'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError': 30,
     'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError': 6,
     'downloader/request_bytes': 3301700,
     'downloader/request_count': 7658,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 7658,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 200927645,
     'downloader/response_count': 7622,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 6848,
     'downloader/response_status_count/301': 637,
     'downloader/response_status_count/302': 8,
     'downloader/response_status_count/404': 129,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 9, 1, 18, 31, 575068),
     'item_scraped_count': 6848,
     'log_count/DEBUG': 14637,
     'log_count/ERROR': 13,
     'log_count/INFO': 42,
     'response_received_count': 6977,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 7658,
     'scheduler/dequeued/disk': 7658,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 7658,
     'scheduler/enqueued/disk': 7658,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 9, 0, 44, 5, 340444)}
2014-10-08 21:18:31-0400 [domain_articles] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Any idea what is causing the stop? I don't understand why it is ending. There are still urls in the urls.txt file. The spider starts working again when delete the urls up until the point the spider has reached and restart it.

Comment: Are you scraping the same domain over and over?

Comment: All of the urls are from the same domain, but I'm scraping different urls.

Comment: Based on the error line 1 (TCP Connection timed out), I'm guessing the http server on the other end has stopped responding because it's blocking you.  I recommend trying at least a 5s delay between requests to any given domain (scrapy has a setting for this).

Comment: Hmmm. The scraping works if I restart it right after scrapy stops working. So if I'm getting banned, I must not be getting banned for long. After how many failed TCP connetions, does Scrapy decide to terminate?